Battery safety after screen replacement
I've recently completed a screen replacement on my Galaxy S20 FE. I got a new screen pre-installed on a frame, so the repair was to basically transplant all the internal components into the new frame. I followed this iFixit guide.
One of the steps was to remove the battery for installation in the new frame. I soaked it in isopropyl alcohol and let it sit a few minutes. Aftewards I used a pick and the flat side of a plastic spudger to pry at the battery from the lower right side (looking from above):


It wasn't too hard but it did take a few minutes and a few attempts.
Afterwards, this is what the side of the battery I pried at looked like:

and zoomed in a bit:

The question: I know lithium ion batteries can be dangerous if damaged - do I need to be concerned about using this battery in my new frame? I reused it because the phone had been used for one year prior to this repair and the battery has 200 cycles, so it hasn't aged much yet.
I suspect I'm overthinking this but I've seen spectacular videos of charged lithium batteries catching fire when damaged and I'm feeling uncertain now.

It is kind of heard to tell in this picture, but is the damage just to the plastic outer cover, or is the metal/plastic shell of the battery physically damaged? I don't mean surface scratches, is it indented or cut? If the casing is not compromised or physically damaged, it should be fine, the issue with batteries like this is if the various layers of internal chemicals come in contact with each other, which generally requires physical damage or something similar.

It's the only photo I took before reassembling the device unfortunately. I did inspect the battery after removing it and didn't see anything immediately concerning, but that's about it. Checking this thoroughly would require the removal of the back cover again I think.

Then at this point I would just use it and monitor for swelling or other issues... Those "spectacular" videos are often setup or extremely unusual situations, it is very rare to have such an extreme and immediate failure at random. If the device is now working, there is little chance you caused enough damage to do anything terrible. Monitor it for a few weeks/charge cycles and see if swelling occurs, if not you are probably fine. There is very little chance it will just "explode" on you.

The comment and answer to your previous question is probably related.

@AndrewT. Somewhat, though that was a different case: an older battery in a different phone that was already in a visibly degraded state either from age or manufacturing defects, this here is more about physical damage
